# Should I use the `lib` folder or the `initializers` folder for Rails monkey patches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, directory, monkeypatching

I have a few functions that monkey patch the string class in a file named `string_class.rb` which is currently placed in the `config\initializers\string_class.rb`.  The code looks like this:

```
class String

  def capitalize_first_char
    self.sub(/^(.)/) { $1.capitalize }
  end

  def capitalize_each_sentence
    self.gsub(/([a-z])((?:[^.?!]|\.(?=[a-z]))*)/i) { $1.upcase + $2.rstrip }
  end

end
```

After doing quite a bit of research I am on the fence if this class should live in the **initializers** or the **lib** folder.

Comment: As an aside, those are poor candidates for patching into string. They're (presumably) purely for display purposes. You should just write helper functions in `app/helpers/*_helper.rb`.

Comment: @meagar I would like them available in ALL controllers and views though, so helpers would be out right?

Comment: No, that's a pretty normal requirement for helpers. If your controllers need them, you would simply define the method in `ApplicationController`. That makes them available to all controllers than inherit from your `ApplicationController`, which should be all of them. Then specify that they're helper methods with [`helper_method :capitalize_first_char, :capitalize_each_sentence`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method), and they'll be available across every view as well.

Comment: @meagar I like this idea better, I will move them there.  If you want to add an answer below I will toss you credit :)

Comment: Mucking about in core classes is almost always a bad idea. Strings are strings, and every Ruby developer expects them to behave in a certain way. Patching new methods into string means that *your* string behaves a little bit differently from every other string. It also means that, should a new version of Ruby introduce a method of the same name (unlikely, admittedly) your code will suddenly be hiding a real String method. In practice it's OK to patch core classes in *extreme* moderation when there is *real* need. This isn't one of those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good place for this sort of thing to live in a Rails application, because it's not the sort of thing you should be doing through the normal course of building a Rails app. Patching core classes is [expressly advised against](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-monkey-patching) in pretty much every style-guide going.

- `config/initializers` is probably the wrong place to do this. Typically this is for setting up dependencies for your app, and most people won't think to look there for code mixing strange methods into core classes
- `lib` is probably a better place, but it's not auto-reloaded by default
- `Gemfile`? If this is worth patching into `String`, it might be worth distilling into a Gem and thoroughly documenting.

I would personally sidestep the problem and simply introduce helper methods. You can make the helper methods available across all controllers by defining them in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`. You can then make the methods available to your views with the [`helper_method`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-monkey-patching) function:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :capitalize_first_char, :capitalize_each_sentence

  #...

  protected

  def capitalize_first_char(str)
    str.sub(/^(.)/) { $1.capitalize }
  end

  def capitalize_each_sentence(str)
    str.gsub(/([a-z])((?:[^.?!]|\.(?=[a-z]))*)/i) { $1.upcase + $2.rstrip }
  end
end
```

Comment: I like where this is going, but have one last question.  Would these helpers belong in the Application Controller or could they go in the Application Helper?

Comment: @meager I got it to work, I had a bad copy and paste. Thank you for the help on this.

Comment: @chrishough ApplicationHelper methods aren't available in the contorller, they're just for views. If you need them in both controller and view, they should go in the controller and be provided to the view via `helper_method`.